# Understanding Hearthstone World Championship match format and decks

Tags: hearthstone, competitive-gaming

As I understand, the match format for the [Hearthstone World Championship](https://playhearthstone.com/en-us/esports/tournament/hct-world-championship-amsterdam/) is [Conquest](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Tournaments#Conquest), where each player uses a number of predefined decks specified by tournament rules.

Where are these decks predefined and who makes them? Are players allowed to make changes to these decks?

If the tournament is played with predefined decks, what makes a player better than another?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decks being predefined means they are created by the players before the event and cannot be changed between or during matches. Players use whatever cards they wish (subject to the usual deckbuilding and format rules).